# T-SQL variable not used in sp_execsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am running a cursor that executes dynamic SQL using a variable.

```
SET @Wk = CAST(@Cntr AS nvarchar(5))
DECLARE @params nvarchar(30) = N'@Wk nvarchar(5)'

--  .. start cursor

EXEC sp_executesql N'ALTER TABLE #Temp DROP COLUMN [WK @WK Sold]', @params, @Wk
```

I get the error

> Msg 4924, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
> ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN failed because column 'WK @WK Sold' does not exist in table #Temp

I know that `@param` and `@Wk` work because I ran

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'select @Wk', @params, @Wk
```

and it worked. I know I can just run

```
EXEC ('ALTER TABLE #Temp DROP COLUMN [WK ' + @Wk + ' Sold]')
```

but I'd like to use `sp_executesql`.

Is it even possible the way I have tried?

Thank you

Comment: The variable is passed fine. The problem is that you think `[WK \r\n    @WK Sold]` (`\r\n` represents carriage return line break) will be parsed and *inject* the value of the variable `@WK` into the to statement. That isn't how SQL works. YOu can't use a variable to replace (part of) an object's name.

Comment: I have to say that if you need a cursor to loop through tables like this then there are bigger issues in the design of this system.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with the variable here. The problem is that you think that a variable/parameter when used in the context of an object results in that variable being injected into the statement. That *doesn't* happen. `SELECT 1 AS [@a]` return return a column aliased as *literally* `@a` *not* a column where the alias is the *value* of a variable called `@a`.

What you need to do here is **safely** inject the value into the dynamic statement and ideally validate the name too:

```sql
DECLARE @Cntr SomeDataType; --I don't know what the datatype should be.

DECLARE @wk nvarchar(5),
        @Column sysname;

SET @wk = @Cntr; --No need for the cast here
SET @Column = (SELECT c.name
               FROM tempdb.sys.tables t
                    JOIN tempdb.sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
               WHERE t.[name] LIKE N'#temp%'
                 AND c.name = N'WK 
    ' + @wk + N' Sold');--Does your column name really have a carriage return and line break in it?

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = N'ALTER TABLE #Temp DROP COLUMN ' + QUOTENAME(@Column) + N';';
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```